# Unable to access Kafka Docker container from outside through java basic app without updating /etc/hosts file

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, containers

**Set up:**
1.Docker Kafka Container which is having Kafka running.
2.Java basic application which produce and consume Kafka messages from outside the Kafka container.

From outside the container I am trying to send Kafka messages using java script and consume those messages with consumer written in java script.
This is working if I am updating etc/hosts file with Kafka container IP address and hostname details.
Please suggest solution to prevent updating etc/hosts file details. 
**Requirement:** With ought updating etc/hosts file how can we access the Kafka container from outside.

Comment: you have to at-least share the docker image details and some of the environment details.

Comment: @rahulmamgain :I cant provide complete Docker file due to confidential matter.

Comment: @rahulmamgain :I cant provide complete Docker file due to confidential matter. Please see below details-  1).Kafka is based on Java8 image. 2).RUN rm /tmp/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz 3).2181 is zookeeper, 9092 is kafka, and 9000 for kafka manager 4)EXPOSE 2181 9092 9000. Then Producer and Consumer is written in basic Java standalone application. This application is running on localhost and kafka container is up on localhost. Starting kafka container by following command - docker run -itd --add-host hostname:hostIP -p 9092:9092 -p 2181:2181 kafka

Answer (score 0):

Got answer for my issue.
Need to provide "Listener" value to "0.0.0.0:9092" in Kafka "server.properties" file.
Updated Docker file for kafka so that when container is up for Kafka it should have below value for Listener in Kafka container.

Kafka Container>config>Server.properties>Listener=0.0.0.0:9092.

Once this is done just start the Kafka container with port forwarding for Zookeeper and Kafka ports with localhost. And then you are able to send the Kafka messages from local to Kafka container and also able to consume those messages from outside the Kafka container.